# Unable to load the requested class: Fpdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, fpdf

I'm using Codeigniter 3 in put the my program in my server.

My libraries are set to:

```php
$autoload['libraries'] = array('fpdf', 'Template', 'database', 'session', 'table', 'form_validation');
```

But I get the error **Unable to load the requested class: Fpdf**

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Have you seen the fpdf library under `application/libraries` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Fpdf library isn't provided with Codeigniter. You must install/copy in the `application/libraries` folder before you can load it.